# How to populate an inline admin form using a GROUP BY query

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a `TabularInline` class, `StockPartInlines` in the inline form view I am trying to populate with a query that GROUPs based on two fields (container_id, expiration_date) and adds an additional field that is a SUM of an existing field.

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part,
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                             related_name='stock')
    container = models.ForeignKey(StorageContainer,
                                  on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                  related_name='items',
                                  null=True)
    quantity_change = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    expiration_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class PartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [StockPartInlines]

class StockPartInlines(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Stock
    fields = ['container', 'expiration_date', 'quantity']
    readonly_fields = ['quantity']

    def quantity(self, obj):
        return obj._quantity
```

The equivalent SQL statement would be;

```
SELECT
    part_id,
    container_id,
    expiration_date,
    SUM(quantity_change)
FROM
    inventory_stock
WHERE
    part_id = part_id
GROUP BY
    container_id,
    expiration_date;
```

I have tried to get this to work by overriding the 'get_queryset()' method of `StockPartInlines`

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(StockPartInlines, self).get_queryset(request)
                                          .values('container','expiration_date')
                                          .order_by('container')
                                          .annotate(_quantity=Sum('quantity_change'))
        return qs
```

This has been returning an error of `'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'`, [traceback](https://dpaste.com/4QYXN5DCN). I believe this is because using .values() in a queryset returns a queryset of dicts rather than a queryset of objects.

Is there a different approach I could take to display the results of this query as an inline form in the admin panel?

Comment: What is the purpose of having this grouped queryset? Wouldn't this make it hard/impossible to edit related objects in the inline?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington
Yes, there is no need to edit or delete the objects. This is for a stock inventory system and each object represents a transaction in the system, for example stock being added or removed from the store. I'm just playing around with different ways to implement this right now, it could be that i'm taking entirely the wrong approach. I had thought about using a proxy Model instead.